# Incomplete type not allowed error for built in array

Tags: c++, arrays

When i am trying to declare this cursed array it tells me incomplete type not allowed, i have made it myself and when it didn't work for no reason i got the same piece of code from the tutorial i'm following (lessons on a site) and it still didn't work , any help ?

```
#include <iostream>
enum CardSuit
{
    SUIT_CLUB,
    SUIT_DIAMOND,
    SUIT_HEART,
    SUIT_SPADE,
    MAX_SUITS
};

enum CardRank
{
    RANK_2,
    RANK_3,
    RANK_4,
    RANK_5,
    RANK_6,
    RANK_7,
    RANK_8,
    RANK_9,
    RANK_10,
    RANK_JACK,
    RANK_QUEEN,
    RANK_KING,
    RANK_ACE,
    MAX_RANKS
};
struct Card
{
    CardRank rank;
    CardSuit suit;
};

int main()
{
std::array<Card, 52> deck {};

    for (int suit = 0; suit < MAX_SUITS; ++suit)
        for (int rank = 0; rank < MAX_RANKS; ++rank)
        {
            deck[card].suit = static_cast<CardSuit>(suit);
            deck[card].rank = static_cast<CardRank>(rank);
            ++card;
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't paraphrase the error message, instead, copy and paste into the question.

Comment: What is the **exact** error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `#include <array>`

Also:

These are wrong:

```
        deck[card].suit = static_cast<CardSuit>(suit);
        deck[card].rank = static_cast<CardRank>(rank);
```

Indexing (`deck[ index ]`) should be done using integral types, and `card` is not declared.

```
size_t card=0; // add this

for (int suit = 0; suit < MAX_SUITS; ++suit)
    for (int rank = 0; rank < MAX_RANKS; ++rank)
    {
        deck[card].suit = static_cast<CardSuit>(suit);
        deck[card].rank = static_cast<CardRank>(rank);
        ++card;
    }
```